# llegalStateException: Unable to locate element by xpath for com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.TextPage

Tags: xpath, selenium, htmlunit

All of a sudden all my tests stopped working. Error message I get is

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate element by xpath for com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.TextPage@11d1aa6
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementByXPath(HtmlUnitDriver.java:796)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:344)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1251)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1248)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.implicitlyWaitFor(HtmlUnitDriver.java:991)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1248)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:397)
```

Pointing on line

```
  WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'/index.html')]"));
```

My driver initialization

```
public class ExtendedHtmlUnitDriver extends HtmlUnitDriver {

public ExtendedHtmlUnitDriver(boolean enableJavascript) {
    super(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_10);
    this.setJavascriptEnabled(enableJavascript);
    this.getWebClient().setCssEnabled(false);

}
```

Tell me what's wrong!

Restarting computer seemed to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

`DomNode` is the HtmlUnit class that provides the [`getByXPath(String)`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#getByXPath%28java.lang.String%29) method. If you're getting a `TextPage` then you shouldn't use such a method as HtmlUnit couldn't recognize a DOM tree in the resulting page.

PS: I wonder how restarting your computer could have fixed this. Can you provide more detail?